# Problem using RFID RC522 with Arduino

Tags: arduino, rfid, firmware, mfrc522

I am using an RFID RC522 with Arduino but, Arduino is not detecting the RFID connected to it, its showing error. so for this, i ordered a new RFID reader and still, the problem remains the same, I tried using a different Arduino, and still no change. please help me

the error is =
Firmware Version: 0x0 = (unknown)
 WARNING: Communication failure, is the MFRC522 properly connected?

Comment: It's not a good idea to try to put pressure on us by claiming your problem is urgent. If that is the case, find and pay someone to do what you urgently.

Comment: Are you using a Mega2560?

Comment: Soldering the pins helped in my case.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when Arduino fails to communicate with your RFID reader. And that happens only when you blindly code something and do something else with circuit connections. You need to recheck these connections and **make sure that it's consistent with what you defined in the code**, and you are ready to go.

SCK of RFID --> SCK of Arduino

SDA --> SS (SDA, if using I2C communication)

MOSI  --> MOSI

MISO --> MISO  (SCL, if using I2C communication)

RST --> (as defined in your code)

GND --> GND

3.3 --> 3.3